# Discret Markov Chain. I have 2 boxes with N balls in each box. N of the 2N balls are white and N are black

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $N = 2,3,4,...$ We have 2 boxes with $N$ balls in each box. $N$ of the $2N$ balls are white and $N$ are black. In each step we take an random ball from each box and swich them around. The state is the number of white balls in the the first box.

- I need to Find the transition probability matrix??
- and find the state transition diagram?

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: You need to find $P_{ij} = P[W(t+1)=j|W(t)=i]$.  Can you find $P[W(t+1)=3|W(t)=8]$?  Can you find $P[W(t+1)=3|W(t)=4]$? Say, assuming $N>8$?

Comment: I must say, I have no Idea how to find it. I assume that the probability that is $\frac{3}{8}+\frac{4}{8}$?

Comment: Let us suppose that $N=10$.  Can you describe to me what would need to happen for $W(t)=8$ to transition to $W(t+1)=3$?  And, what would need to happen for $W(t)=4$ to transition to $W(t+1) = 3$?  Here I am assuming $W(t)$ is the number of white balls in box 1 at time step $t \in\{0, 1, 2, ...\}$.

Comment: From $w(t)=8$ to $w(t+1)= 3$ it will have to Lose 5 White  balls?, and from $w(t)=4$ to $w(t+1) = 3$ it will have to lose 1 white ball?

Comment: Yes, and so what is the probability of loosing 5 white balls on a single turn?  Also, to get the probability of loosing 1 white ball by going from 4 to 3 (given $W(t)=3$) you need to describe in more detail what happens when we loose that ball.

Comment: And that of course 0. So we can say w(t+1)= n-1, where n is the number of balls?

Comment: I agree $P_{83}=0$.  I do not agree that the number of white balls always decreases by 1, or is always the constant $n-1$.  It might increase with some probability.